# .NET UDP Data Reception

Tags: c#, .net, udp, wireshark

I have a simple UDP listener that I am trying to collect datagrams from. My datagrams can be in one of two data formats. With the first data format, I am receiving data in my program as expected. With the second, there is absolutely no indication that data is ever received from my program, even though I can verify that the UDP data is passing onto the the network interface via Wireshark. I thought that maybe these were malformed UDP packets that Windows was rejecting but Wireshark does label them as UDP. My code is below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thdUdpServer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(serverThread));
        thdUdpServer.Start();
    }

    static void serverThread()
    {

        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(0), 2000));

        while (true)
        {
            byte[] responseData = new byte[128];
            socket.Receive(responseData);
            string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseData);
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " " + returnData);

        }
```

The missing packets are all 29 byte datagrams that look something like this (translated to ASCII).

```
#01RdFFFF...?...... ........F
```

Why would Wireshark indicate their presence but .NET not seem to see them?

Answer (score 2):

If the bytes contain non-printable ASCII characters, you may not see them on the Console.

Comment: For clarification, I am trying to print DateTime.Now with the returned data and still don't see anything.

Comment: What does the 29 byte datagram contain? Can you post the first few bytes?

Comment: I've added an example of the datagram in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

There's something missing in your code. It should be throwing a socket exception when calling ReceiveFrom (at least according to MSDN, haven't tried your code.)

You should bind your socket to the address:port you want to listen on (or use 0.0.0.0 as the address to listen on any local address):

```
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(0), 2000);
```

The EndPoint in ReceiveFrom is not the listening port for the server. It's the address you want to receive packets from. You can use an Endpoint of 0.0.0.0:0 to receive from any host.

After returning from the method the Endpoint will be filled with the address of the host that sent the packet (client).

You can use Receive instead of ReceiveFrom if you don't care about the client end point.
Likely your client is not sending packets from 192.168.1.100:2000, and that is why you are not receiving them; thought why you're not getting an exception when calling ReceiveFrom is beyond me.

Also:
There is no need to call Convert.ToInt32 in:

```
new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.100"), Convert.ToInt32(2000));
```

2000 is already an int.

Comment: I think the exception thing may be because it is running in a separate thread. I'll have to run the code...

Comment: You are correct. I don't know why I left the bind statement out. I've changed the method to Receive as well. However, I still don't see any UDP packets from these clients despite their prescence in Wireshark.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that they are not being sent to the correct port or the correct interface, did you bind to 0.0.0.0 or to an specific IP address?

Comment: Sorry re-IP address did not see your code... The only option then is if the packets are not being sent to port 2000. Where is wireshark run (server or client)? The other remote option is a network error.

Comment: Wireshark confirms that the packets are being sent to UDP port 2000 on the server.

Comment: In looking at Wireshark, all the UDP checksums are marked as invalid for these particular packets.